# setOnClickListener is not working inside CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I have a ListView and I have my own customized ListItem I am applying action listener on them but they are not responding to event.

```
private class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FriendInfo> {

        public CustomAdapter (Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                ArrayList<FriendInfo> friendList) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, friendList);


        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;           

            try {
                if (v == null) {
                    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.friend_item, null);
                }               

                 if(isViewInvitations){
                    Button btn_AcceptFrndReq = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btnAcceptFrndReq);
                    Button btn_DelFrnd = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btnDelFrnd);
                    btn_DelFrnd.setClickable(true);
                    btn_AcceptFrndReq.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    btn_DelFrnd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                    btn_AcceptFrndReq.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View arg0) {                    
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Accept", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

                        }
                    });
                    btn_DelFrnd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View arg0) {        
                            //do delete call here in new thread
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Delete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        }
                    });

                }
```

Comment: @Ajzaz: Can you post your complete code in pastebin.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 thing to notice is that when you create your toast, you don't show it.

Change:

```
Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Accept", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
```

to

```
Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Accept", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

If the toast still doesnt show up, try getting the context from the `View` that is passed to `onClick`

```
Toast.makeText(arg0.getContext(), "Accept", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
implements View.OnClickListener and override public void onClick(View v) { method 

and all done
```